# Override handling for basic/primitive types within a scope

Tags: c#, nlp, overriding

I'd like to be able to make code that looks like this:

```
30, 60, 90
```

And have it make a `List<int>` with those numbers in it. The problem is that in order to do this I believe I would need to be able to override how an `int` works within this scope. Is there any way that I could have my own "Int" class that could be used within a specific scope whenever a primitive constant like `30` was entered? If I'm unable to override `int` then the class must be used explicitly in this scope I'll end up with something like this:

```
Int(30),Int(60),Int(90)
```

Which is still less code than the standard way:

```
var nums = new List<int>(); nums.Add(30); nums.Add(60); nums.Add(90);
```

or even:

```
var nums = new List<int>{ 30, 60, 90 };
```

I'm playing around with my own scripting language, for education purposes only, not intended for anyone else to use. I'm trying to see how far I can simplify syntax to read closer to a natural language. Is something like in first code block at the top of this question possible? If this is possible, can I extend it to other primitive types?

EDIT: I want something that is pure C#, I'm not doing my own parsing, or writing my own compiler. I'm curious if somehow I can have a primitive type like a constant int be handled through my own type instead? I don't think it's possible, but if not at least StackOverflow is good at giving alternatives I might not have thought about.

Ok, here's what I've come up with so far to get me closer:

```
public static class Values
{
    static public List<int> Make(params int[] vals)
    {
        return vals.ToList();
    }
}
```

This lets me do something like:

```
var nums = Values.Make(30, 60, 90);
```

Of course, this isn't much shorter than `var nums = new List<int>{ 30, 60, 90 };` but it lets me abstract the int away so they could also do:

```
var nums = Values.Make(30.0f, 60.0f, 90.0f);
```

So long as I make a handler for a list of floats. Unfortunately if I make a generic method, like this:

```
public static List<T> Make<T>(params T[] vals) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return vals.ToList();
}
```

Then it make the syntax of using it longer:

```
var nums = Values.Make<float>(30.0f, 60.0f, 90.0f);
```

Comment: it's difficult to understand what you are actually asking. Are you writing your own compiler? Modifying C# compiler? Are you referring to syntax of "your own scripting language" or C# syntax?

Comment: Are you looking for a [collection initializer](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/collection-initializers/) in C#, or implementing a parser?  If you're implementing a parser, doesn't wrapping the items you want to collect in braces make sense, since that's mathematical set syntax anyway?

Comment: I'll add more detail to the question. I want something that is pure C#, I'm not doing my own parsing, or writing my own compiler. I'm curious if somehow I can have a primitive type like a constant int be handled through my own type instead. I don't think it's possible, but if not at least SO is good at giving alternatives I might not have thought about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on C# 4.0 you can simplify it to:

```
var nums = new[] { 30, 60, 90 };
```

which will create an `int[]`. This can also be used with other types:

```
var floats = new[] { 30.0f, 60.0f, 90.0f };
```

If you really need a `List<T>` then you can do:

```
var nums = new[] { 30, 60, 90 }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Smoak had the cleanest and most efficient way to implement the specific situation I was describing, but if you would like to see how you can actually override handling for basic primitive types, here's an example.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        // This lets you add new functionality to the primitive type 'int'
        // Allowing you to do (10).Add(5) to give you a List<int> with {10, 5}
        public static List<int> And( this int num, int other )
        {
            return new List<int> { num, other };
        }

        public static List<int> And( this List<int> num, int other )
        {            
            num.Add(other);
            return num;
        }
    }
}

// ===========================================================================
// And Program.cs
using ExtensionMethods;

namespace SyntaxTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {            
            var nums = (30).And(60).And(90);

            nums.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n + "\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

With output that looks like:

```
30

60

90
```

In addition to be less elegant than Smoak's answer, it is also less efficient, this line of code `var nums = (30).And(60).And(90);`, creates an int, then makes a list with two ints, then makes a list with three ints, whereas `var nums = new[] {30, 60, 90};` just makes a list with three ints.

Comment: While I agree that your solution is not elegant and I would be against using it, it *is* efficient. Calling `Add()` on existing list should be pretty fast.

Comment: @svick: Calling `Add()` would be if doing something like `(10)` made a `List<int>`, but in my example `(10)` just allows you to use the `.` operator on a primitive `int`, which then allows for use of any extension methods you have created for that type, within the current namespace, like I did with `Add()`.